# skyline storage integration to Cholesky decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I'm trying to develop direct solver for FEM application, solver uses Cholesky decomposition(with following code) but without skyline storage technique, so my question is 2 fold:

1)Comprising skyline diagonal normally one have to travel along the row and whenever you come across the zeros you simply skip them and proceed to non zero values, in between zeros are stored also. So based on tha skyline composition sceheme how am I supposed to integrate the skyline storage technique into the below code snippet?

2) AFAIU skyline sceheme is only intended for storage purposes, but it will not contribute to the solution in terms of speed other than saving memory, if that storage increase the speed at all. For example, Cholesky decom. solves 2000x2000 matrix in 20sec, after integrating skyline will I be able to solve that in 4-6 sec?

If it doesn't bring such drastic increase in solution speed, I will switch to the other solution strategies e.g. preconditioned conjugate gradient, etc..

```
subroutine Chodec(y,K, f)
! K*y = f  linear algebraic equation 
implicit none
integer::l,i,n,j, step
real(iwp)::clii, cii2,gik, gij, clij, cljj, aii, aij,clii2, clik, gjk, sum, ak, bi, xi, yi, gki
real(iwp),allocatable::u(:)
real(iwp),intent(out):: y(:)
real(iwp),intent(in out)::f(:),K(:,:)
!print *, K
n = ubound(K,1)
!print *, K
      i = 1
      aii = K(1,1)
      clii = sqrt(aii)
      K(1,1) = clii
!...decompose each row in turn
   do 20 i=2,n !...work along the row
        do 10 j=1,i-1
          cljj = K(j,j)
          aij = K(i,j)
          sum = 0.0
          do  l=1,j-1
            gik = K(i,l)
            gjk = K(j,l)
            sum = sum + gik*gjk
          end do
          clij = (aij - sum)/cljj
          K(i,j) = clij
   10   continue
!...finally find the diagonal entry on the row
        aii = K(i,i)
        sum = 0.0
        do 15 l=1,i-1
          clik = K(i,l)
          sum = sum + clik*clik
   15   continue
        clii2 = aii - sum
        clii = sqrt(clii2)
        K(i,i) = clii
   20 continue
   !c...forward substitution: solve Ly = f
   !print *, k
      y(1) = f(1)/K(1,1)
      do  i=2,n
        bi = f(i)
        sum = 0.0
        do l=1,i-1
          gik = K(i,l)
          ak = y(l)
          sum = sum - gik*ak
        end do     !5   continue
        clii = K(i,i)
        y(i) = (bi - sum)/clii
      end do
        !10 continue

        !...back-substitution phase: solve L x = y
        n = ubound(K,1)
    allocate(u(n))
      u(n) = y(n)/K(n,n)
      do i=n-1,1, step -1
        yi = y(i)
        sum = 0.0
        do l=i+1,n
          gki = K(l,i)
          ak = u(l)
          sum = sum + gki*ak
        end do !15   continue
        clii = K(i,i)
        u(i) = (yi - sum)/clii
   end do !20 continue
y = u
!!
```